# calculating average using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, average

```
function averageCalculator (numvalues) {

    for(i=0, i <= numvalues, i++>) {
    var score = prompt("input the score")
    result1 += score;

    }

    alert(result1 / 3);
}
```

this function is later triggered by a button with `onclick="averageCalculator (2)`

```
<input type="button" value="Click for the average" onclick="averageCalculator (2)">
```

any ideas why its not working? it should prompt you for 2 values and then alert you with the average. not sure whats wrong.

Comment: What is happening now?  Wrong answer or code not executing?

Comment: You probably want to change the alert to `alert(result1 / numvalues);`

Comment: im getting ReferenceError: averageCalculator is not defined so code not executing. seems to be defined as a function though... not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues. The for loop is not well-formatted and you need to terminate statements with a semi-colon. Also, you need to declare variables. And your loop will run `numvalues`+1 times which is why I removed the `=` in your loop. Also if you want to calculate an average you want to divide by `numvalues`.

```
function averageCalculator (numvalues) {
var result1 = 0;
for(let i=0; i < numvalues; i++) {    
    var score = prompt("input the score");   
    result1 += score;    
}
alert(result1 / numvalues);
}
```

`numvalues` represents the number of inputs you want to calculate average for.

On top of the invalid syntax you will run into a common "problem" with javascript here. The inputs are treated as strings and instead of being added they will be concatenated. Providing 2 and 2 as scores will result in 11. 2 concatenated with 2 = 22 / 2 = 11. You need to cast the value to a number explicitly before adding them together:

```
function averageCalculator (numvalues) {
var result1 = 0;
for(i=0; i < numvalues; i++) {    
    var score = prompt("input the score");   
    result1 += Number(score);    
}
alert(result1 / numvalues);
}
```

The code above will correctly return 2.

Comment: Please, do not use _boxed_ values! Instead `Number(n)` use `+n`! If you're sure the string contains a number, it's the right way. Otherwise you can `parseInt(n)` it or `parseFloat(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of your for-loop is wrong:

```
for(i=0, i <= numvalues, i++>) {
```

should be

```
for(i=0; i <= numvalues; i++) {
```

Tip: Also, it's better to use

```
for(var i=0; i <= numvalues; i++) {
```

since then `i` will be a local variable instead of a global one.

Comment: U r right JW... and nic also edit the alert() part as mentioned by @richard

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

for(var i=0; i <= numvalues; i++){}

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution (using a functional programming libary, like [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)):

```
function averageCalculator(numValues) {
    var numbers = _.map(_.range(numValues), function(element) {
        return +prompt('input the score');
    });

    var result = _.reduce(numbers, function(memo, number) {
        return memo + number;
    }, memo);

    alert(result / 3);
}
```

While a little bit more complicated (and less efficient), you'll get rid of loops altogether.

**EDIT**

The `+prompt('input the score')` does effectivly the same as `Number(prompt('input the score'))`.